# OpenCV calcOpticalFlowFarnebackのビルドエラー

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

OpenCV3.2、VisualStudio2015の環境で、calcOpticalFlowFarneback関数を使用しましたが、ビルド時につぎのエラーが出ました。

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(392,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (MomentumAnalysisTool.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
1>OpticalFlowDlg.obj : error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "void __cdecl cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputOutputArray const &,double,int,int,int,int,double,int)" (?calcOpticalFlowFarneback@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@0AEBV_InputOutputArray@1@NHHHHNH@Z) が関数 "public: void __cdecl COpticalFlowDlg::OnBnClickedButton1(void)" (?OnBnClickedButton1@COpticalFlowDlg@@QEAAXXZ) で参照されました。
1>C:\WORK\OpticalFlow\x64\Debug\OpticalFlow.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 件の未解決の外部参照
```

Libファイルは次を設定しています。
 - opencv_optflow320d.lib
 - opencv_core320d.lib
 - opencv_highgui320d.lib
 - opencv_imgproc320d.lib
 - opencv_videoio320d.lib
 - opencv_tracking320d.lib
 - opencv_features2d320d.lib

不足のlibがありますか？
ご存知の方、ご教示いただければと存じます。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optical Flow関連は`opencv_video320d.lib`ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 仰るとおりopencv_video320(d).libでした。ありがとうございます。どの関数がどのlibか簡単にわかる方法はございますか？

Comment: OpenCV公式QAの質問"[How do we find which function belongs to which opencv library?](http://answers.opencv.org/question/91607/)"にもありますが、公式リファレンスマニュアルから辿るのが良いと思います。（この回答も同じ方法で辿りました）